# Model is defined in dictionary and I want use DataParallel which doesnt support dictionary

Tags: pytorch

my models are defined as dictionaries and I want to use DataParallel which doesn't support dictionaries. I cannot change dictionaries into normal models. Any alternative solution

```
models      = {'backbone': resnet18}
if method =='lloss':
   models = {'backbone': resnet18, 'module': loss_module}
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = True
```

Comment: Why don't you code your model as a PyTorch `nn.Module` class?

Comment: My code has multiple models, each model is using a different architecture. SO it was easy to implement in dictionary but now the problem is DataParallel cannot be used with dictionary

Comment: Have you tried with `ModuleDict` (or `ModuleList`)?

Comment: No, I didn’t try these two